# How can I know how many lines were last inserted by Datagridview into Oracle

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, oracle11g

I'm programming an application that DataGridView should insert into Oracle after clicking a button. How can I know how many lines were last inserted into Oracle. At best a message should appear. Thanks

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewDoubleBuffered1.Rows.Count - 1; i++) //Schleife für INSERT Befehl
            {

                OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(XXXXXXX);
                con.Open();

                string sql = "INSERT INTO AFTERSALES.INPUT_BOARDLEVEL_REPAIR_LDS (BLR_REPORT_DATE, MONTH_OF_REPAIR_END, PCB_COUNTER) "
                           + "VALUES (:BLR_REPORT_DATE, :MONTH_OF_REPAIR_END, :PCB_COUNTER)";

                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":BLR_REPORT_DATE", Convert.ToString(dataGridViewDoubleBuffered1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":MONTH_OF_REPAIR_END", dataGridViewDoubleBuffered1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":PCB_COUNTER", dataGridViewDoubleBuffered1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery returns number of rows affected.

So,

```
var numRowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you give me please a sample.

Comment: @Yves - I provided a code sample already.  If anything's not clear, feel free to ask.  Note that since you are in a loop, you may need to add to the variable (e.g. numRowsInserted += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()).

Answer (score 0):

```
int recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2:

> Returns Int32 For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return
>   value is the number of rows affected by the command.